# Building in Jenkins by perforce changelist that is deduced automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

I'm using a Jenkins server to build my project. My SCM is perforce, so I installed the P4 plugin of Jenkins.

Before building my project, I run a windows batch script from Jenkins that checkouts a file, changes it, and resubmit it. I save the changelist of the build in a file. The whole process looks like this:

```
C:\> p4 edit buildDescription.txt
C:\> editBeforeBuild.exe buildDescription.txt
C:\> p4 submit -d "Change description before build" buildDescription.txt >> ChangelistRaw.txt
C:\> GetChangelistNum.exe ChangelistRaw.txt >> changeListFinal.txt
```

I want to build my project according to that changelist.

Luckily, there is an option in the p4 plugin GUI of building by label (which can also work with changelist or time).

[image: Marked with red pen]

I guess I need to set an environmental variable in a way that will be available for the P4 plugin. I tried to do it in the above script, but the environmental variables weren't recognized by the p4 plugin.

My question is: How do I set an environmental variable before p4 runs, in a way that it will be recognized by it? Or is there any other way to build my project without including files that were submitted after the submission that I mentioned above?

Comment: Are you asking how Perforce labels work? Try reading about the `p4 tag` command. It seems like, rather than editing the changelist into a submitted file in order to perform your build, you should create a Perforce label that specifies which revisions to use in order to perform your build.

Comment: So you're suggesting to create a unique label on each build? So same question. How would the build know what's the label it should build by?

Comment: It looks like you can hardcode a label in there -- so I guess you could just have your script update that specific label?  Doesn't seem very safe if you might have multiple builds going at once.  Do you have any access in your script to the workspace that Jenkins is going to use?  Maybe you could just run your sync command there and tell Jenkins not to sync anything?

Comment: Of course, that is possible. I could only run my own script from Jenkins, using no plugins at all. But I would assume that there is a way, otherwise this option is pretty much useless...